# How to rewrite javascript function with php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a script.I will show sample.

```
    <form>    
    <textarea id='input'></textarea>
    <input onclick="convert()" value="go function" />
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" >

function convert() {
src = document.getElementById("input").value;
document.getElementById("output").value = Z1_Uni(src);
}

function Z1_Uni(input)
{
   var output=input;
   var tallAA = "\u102B";
   var AA = "\u102C";
   var vi = "\u102D";
   var ii = "\u102E";
   var u = "\u102F";
   var uu = "\u1030";
}
</script>
```

This  sample will be show output result with javascript.I want to rewrite with php.

sample is following.

```
<form action="convert.php" method="post">
<textarea id="input" name="input"></textarea>
<input type="submit" Value="go to convert page">
</form>
```

Convert.php

```
<?php $input=$_POST['input'];

$output=(?????????????? );
//(Here javascript function will be work.I want to know this step.)
?>
```

Sample link is here http://mrdba.info/zawgyi-converter/

Comment: Not quite sure what the question is here. Can you clear it up a bit? Also, you typed "</scrtipt>" instead of "</script>".

Comment: Does your example JS code work? I don't see any return statement so it is likely not working.

Comment: Ok friend,Now I will be edit. Thanks.

Comment: var tallAA = "\u102B";
   var AA = "\u102C";
   var vi = "\u102D";
   var ii = "\u102E";
   var u = "\u102F";
   var uu = "\u1030";

What is the function of these?

Comment: `Z1_Uni` return nothing, what do you want to do ???

Comment: Zi_uni is font convertor for Our language.you will see this code sample is [link]http://mrdba.info/zawgyi-converter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to describe some kind of Javascript Unicode encoding function similar to the one here:

http://centralupload.com/files/16995_7p7sw/akyinnarnantaw.txt

This function encodes specific characters to their unicode representations EG: '\u102C'

In php, you can use json_encode for this:

```
<?php
$input = "你好";

$output = json_encode(utf8_encode($input));

echo $output;
?>
```